# convert /dev/md0 to /dev/sda1

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, mdadm, raid1

I used a Software-RAID I and want to access the data without RAID now.

After

```
mdadm --fail /dev/md0 /dev/sda1
mdadm --remove /dev/md0 /dev/sda1
```

I tried

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

but dmesg says

```
[ 5620.788838] EXT4-fs (sdb1): ext4_check_descriptors: Block bitmap for group 1 not in group (block 0)!
[ 5620.788841] EXT4-fs (sdb1): group descriptors corrupted!
```

Isn't it possible to convert a RAID-partition to non-RAID? Do I have to copy all files to another partition, delete the RAID partition and create a new file system?

Comment: That would be enough for a layout where the metadata is at the end of the volume, but as Stéphane explains you seem to have the metadata at the beginning, which makes this more difficult. [Background](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/54960/how-to-set-up-disk-mirroring-in-ubuntu/55044#55044) (and other way round).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's metadata at the start of the partition. If you do a

```
mdadm -E /dev/sda1
```

you'll see where the data starts (*Data Offset*). That will be where your FS starts. You could use fdisk (for MBR-type partitioning) or gdisk (for GPT), to move the start of sda1 to the location of that *Data Offset*.

For instance, if it says:

```
Data Offset : 16384 sectors
```

Run `fdisk -u`, print the current partition table with `p`, note the start and end of the partition, delete it and recreate it with the first sector being the old one plus 16384.