# How to mount/recover data on a disk that was part of a mdadm raid 1 on another machine?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, data-recovery, software-raid

### Some background

- The disk itself was "worked on" by a friend and is said to be still intact, undamaged and still mountable/recoverable
- The disk was part of a software raid 1 on Ubuntu 12.04
- The other disk in the original raid 1 was formatted and used for another purpose, leaving the current disk (the one in question) still technically part of a raid that no longer exists

### What I have tried already

- Basic mounting

  - I added an entry to fstab, marked the disk as ext3/ext4 and tried to mount.
  - Upon mounting the following error appears

    `wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on`
  - And in **dmesg**

    `EXT4-fs (sdc1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem`
- I have tried to find the file system type of the disk and have come up with

  `$sudo file -s /dev/sdc`
  `/dev/sdc: x86 boot sector; partition 1: ID=0x83, starthead 254, startsector 63, 1953520002 sectors, code offset 0xb8`

### Where I need some help / My Questions

- Is there a way to convert the disk to ext4 without damaging the data?
- Is there a simple way to mount the Linux 83 file type disk and recover the data?
- I have another disk currently free in case it is a possibility to somehow rebuild the raid
- My main goal is to recover the data from the disk. I am open to all options.

### Update

Some commands' output

- **fdisk -l /dev/sdc**

  `$fdisk -l /dev/sdc`

  `Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes`
  `255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors`
  `Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes`
  `Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes`
  `I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes`
  `Disk identifier: 0x0005ed9c`

  `Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System`
  `/dev/sdc1              63  1953520064   976760001   83  Linux`
- **file -s /dev/sdc1**

  `$file -s /dev/sdc1`
  `/dev/sdc1: data`
- **hexdump -C -n 32256 /dev/sdc** (Not sure if this could help or not)

  ```
  $hexdump -C -n 32256 /dev/sdc`
  00000000  fa b8 00 10 8e d0 bc 00  b0 b8 00 00 8e d8 8e c0  |................|
  00000010  fb be 00 7c bf 00 06 b9  00 02 f3 a4 ea 21 06 00  |...|.........!..|
  00000020  00 be be 07 38 04 75 0b  83 c6 10 81 fe fe 07 75  |....8.u........u|
  00000030  f3 eb 16 b4 02 b0 01 bb  00 7c b2 80 8a 74 01 8b  |.........|...t..|
  00000040  4c 02 cd 13 ea 00 7c 00  00 eb fe 00 00 00 00 00  |L.....|.........|
  00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
  *
  000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  9c ed 05 00 00 00 00 fe  |................|
  000001c0  ff ff 83 fe ff ff 3f 00  00 00 82 59 70 74 00 00  |......?....Ypt..|
  000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
  *
  000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
  00000200  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
  *
  00007e00
  ```

Comment: The problem is that the partition thinks it has some raid volume on it and not an ext4fs. And the kernel is right. However as it was a raid 1 it happens to be an ext4fs. a `mount -f ext4 /dev/sdc1 /mountpoint` should do the trick. To force mount to assume ext4 instead of _looking_ for a file system is what -f does

Comment: The force mount doesn't give any errors, but the mount point is blank. Either the data is gone, or the mount didn't work as expected. Doing a `df` shows me that the newly mounted disk is 2% in use which is significantly lower than expected.

Comment: @user1129682, if mount says it isn't ext4, then it isn't... trying to force it isn't going to help.

Comment: @psusi: worked for me. Gilles answer explainns why it works under some circumstances

Comment: @Bananguin Don't you mean `mount -t ext4`? The -f flag is for 'fake' mounting (ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: @Quantum7: yes, you are right, but i cant edit the comment anymore

Answer (score 22):

This is working excellently in Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo -i
mdadm --assemble --scan
```

You will get:

```
mdadm: /dev/md/1 has been started with 1 drive (out of 2)
```

Then mount and see your files:

```
cd /mnt && mkdir to-restore-md1 && mount /dev/md1 to-restore-md1
ls -la to-restore-md1
```

Comment: Was getting "exists but is not an md array" on a failed hard drive that was part of an array... and this worked better than all the other suggestions. Mounted successfully, busy copying data off right now.

Comment: this option worked well for me.  2 Intel SSD's in RAID1.  Pulled one and slaved off SATA port to pc running suse linux.  Initially shows up as only `/dev/sdc` and as `/dev/md127`.  Then did `mdadm --assemble --scan` which resulted in `/dev/md/Volume0_0p1` and `/dev/md/Volume0_0p2` and so on corresponding to 4 partitions that were on the disk.  P2 was the one i needed so: `mkdir /p2`  followed by `mount   /dev/md/Volume0_0p2   /p2` mounted it which was EXT3 and i can easily access and copy the data.  It also mounted it as read-write.

Comment: sometimes the `--scan` mode does not start arrays with missing disks, in my case here I had to stop the auto-assembled array and start it again with `mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md/1 /dev/sdc1`

Comment: mdadm --assemble --scan will give you: mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically

Answer (score 7):

Linux mdraid has [several metadata formats](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_superblock_formats). Formats 0.9 and 1.0 put the metadata at the end of the containing device, and the payload (the filesystem) starts at the beginning of the device and can be accessed directly without going through the raid layer. Formats 1.1 and 1.2 put the metadata at the middle and beginning of the containing device respectively, so the payload is at an offset.

The Ubuntu installer creates volumes with the 1.2 metadata format, so your data starts after the metadata instead of at the beginning of the device.

The simplest way to access that data is to assemble the raid device. In a RAID-1 volume, a single device is sufficient.

```
madadm -A /dev/sdc1
```

---

(Stop here unless you like pain.)

You can also access the data at an offset. The only point I can see to doing this is if you have to work in a very old kernel that doesn't support 1.x mdraid formats. First, determine the offset `mdadm -E /dev/sdc1`: look for the line `Data Offset : SSS sectors`. An mdadm sector is 512 bytes.

```
sectors=$(mdadm -E /dev/sdc1 | awk -F: '$1 ~ /Data offset/ {print $2}')
bytes=$(($sectors * 512))
losetup -f -o $bytes /dev/sdc1
```

In desperation, with 1.x formats, the data offset is stored in bytes 128–135 of the metadata, little-endian¹. 1.2 metadata is 4096 bytes after the beginning of the device.

You can also change the partition table to make it start further. Be very careful with your arithmetic. Only do that if you want to keep using the disk on a long-term basis in an old system that can't access the raid device.

¹  <sub>Or with platform endianness? I'm not sure.</sub>

Comment: the data can start at different offsets (see `mdadm -E /dev/sdc1` for where exactly) but certainly not at 4k for 1.2  metadata, since 4k is precisely where the metadata is stored. See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57477/22565

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Oops, yes, brain fart. Thanks.

Comment: `mdadm -A /dev/sdc1` outputs `mdadm: device /dev/sdc1 exists but is not an md array.` I've gone a bit further to use mdadm and see if there is any additional info... `mdadm --misc --examine /dev/sdc1` outputs `mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdc1.`. Is there a way that I can re-write the superblocks on this disk to mark it as an available disk for RAID assembly?

Comment: @Gilles A `mdadm -E /dev/sdc` returns the following for me: `/dev/sdc:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   1953520002 sectors at           63 (type 83)
` but no information for /dev/sdc1 though

Comment: @Adam Are you sure the disk wasn't written to since it last worked? Please post the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sdc` and `file -s /dev/sdc1`.

Comment: I cannot be completely sure the disk wasn't written to since it last worked - it was in the hands of someone else and I'm taking their word. See the update in the original question for the output of the commands.

Comment: @Adam Either you're running an old system that doesn't support mdraid 1.x formats (if so, try another Ubuntu 12.04, or a recent Sysrescuecd), or the disk has been messed up in some way. Normally `/dev/sda1` should have type fd and not 83, and `file` should recognize the raid volume. Your problem has been upgraded from a simple setup problem to a much harder data recovery problem. Might the disk have been encrypted, or part of a fakeraid (BIOS RAID)?

Comment: @Gilles I'm currently trying to mount the disk on Ubuntu 12.04. It is a fresh install as of 2 weeks ago and I only use it for coding. I think it is more likely that the disk is messed up somehow. I can vouch that the disk is not encrypted since I had originally setup the software raid. Is it possible to force mdadm to pick up this disk and rebuild a RAID array? Or does it seem that it is too much trouble at this point?

Comment: @Adam If mdadm can't find its metadata there's nothing you can do there: you can't force it to do something since it doesn't know what to do. You need to look for a filesystem, and if psusi's advice doesn't lead anywhere, the outlook is bleak. Maybe a hexdump of the first few kilobytes of the disk could inspire someone (beware that it could expose some confidential data).

Comment: @Gilles Seems like I'm stuck for the moment. I've posted a hexdump if it may help anyone. I'll continue looking into this on my own as well to see if anything comes up. I'm still open to suggestions too!

Answer (score 6):

To my surprise, I was/am able to recover the data by simply using [foremost](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Foremost).

The help received here was invaluable. After trying a variety of suggested combinations, as well as my own mix-ins, the ideal method (to mount and use the disk as normal) didn't seem like an option any more. Resorting to data recovery is my solution in this case.

Comment: I realize this was a while ago! But do you remember whether you were able to use foremost without mounting the partition?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember the details of this anymore. :/

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you have already zapped the mdadm superblock.  If it used to be there and was format 1.1 or 1.2, then most likely the filesystem is at offset 2048 sectors.  You can run `e2fsck /dev/sdc1?offset=2048` to force it to look for the filesystem starting at that offset.  If it finds it then you can modify your partition table to point to where the filesystem actually starts.  You can use `parted /dev/sdc` and the `unit s` command to use units of sectors.  `print` the table, note the start and end sector, then `rm` the partition, then recreate it with `mkpart` and use the same end sector, but add the offset to the start sector.

If 2048 does not work, you might also try 1985.

Comment: Running `e2fsck /dev/sdc1?offset=2048` (I also ran offset=1985) outputs `Bad magic number..Superblock invalid...` as well as suggesting that the superblock is corrupt and trying to run e2fsck with an alternative superblock. Seems like I should provide it an alternative superblock to move forward.

Comment: @Adam, no, you just need to get the correct offset.  `testdisk` should be able to do a detailed scan and fix the partition table for you.

Comment: `testdisk` is completely new territory for me. A basic run (Analyse) show `No ext2, JFS, Reiser.. marker. Bad relative sector. No partition is bootable.` It also provides the following: `1 P Linux                    0   1  1 121600 254 63 1953520002` How can I make sense of that in order to help the situation?

Comment: @Adam, I've never used it myself, I just know it is supposed to be able to scan for and find the superblock.  You did run it on the whole disk, not the partition right?

Comment: After running an analysis on the full disk, it turned up no partitions. Currently running a _deep_ scan now. If this doesn't turn up anything, I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: The deep scan turned up the same results as the quick scan: No partitions found. I can't see anything to go on as far as testdisk is concerned. Not sure what to do at this point. All suggestions so far have led to a giant wall >.<

Comment: @Adam, then it seems the disk was NOT part of a raid1.  Maybe it was part of some other raid level, in which case, you can not use it alone.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7540/discussion-between-adam-and-psusi)

Comment: Wait, I think the offset actually is in bytes, and the numbers I listed were sectors, so you will need to multiply them by 512.

Comment: I tried 63*512 without any luck. I tried a variety of other offsets as well. 4096 gave the best results. I used `fsck` and it told me that it had reverted the disk to a `ext2` system since the `ext3/4` was corrupted. It then went on to attempt to convert the entire disk to ext2 (I believe so) since it was saying `inode # has illegal blocks...`. I aborted and switched over to `foremost` after that. I may have lot some of the data at the start of the disk - I'll find out soon. >.<