# Syntax of `offset` option of `e2fsck`

Tags: ext4, e2fsck

In [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65011/158661) the user @psusi shows a use of `e2fsck` that I could not find in the documentation: `e2fsck /dev/sdc1?offset=2048`.

I am trying to use it to check a device (manually failed and removed) from a raid array. Long story short: I know that starting from offset 67108864 of /dev/sdb2 there is an ext4 filesystem, which was not properly unmounted. I have tried the following (always reverting `/dev/sdb2` to the same content between different tests).

1. Running `mount /dev/sdb2 -o loop,offset=67108864 /tmp/mnt` works fine and I can see using `dmesg | tail` that it deleted 5 orphaned inodes, fully recovered the filesystem, and mounted it:

   ```
   EXT4-fs: 5 orphan inodes deleted
   EXT4-fs: recovery complete
   EXT4-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
   ```
2. Similarly, `losetup /dev/loop0 --offset 67108864 /dev/sdb2 && e2fsck -n /dev/loop0`:

   ```
   root: recovering journal
   root: Clearing orphaned inode 1179687 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100600, size=16384)
   root: Clearing orphaned inode 1179686 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100600, size=16384)
   root: Clearing orphaned inode 1179685 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100600, size=32768)
   root: Clearing orphaned inode 1179684 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100600, size=32768)
   root: Clearing orphaned inode 1179683 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100600, size=65536)
   root: clean, 225936/4882432 files, 2664100/19514624 blocks
   ```
3. I thought that `e2fsck -p /dev/sdb2?offset=67108864` would be equivalent to the approach above (using `losetup`) but instead I get:

   ```
   root: recovering journal
   e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to re-open root
   root: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********
   ```

   I am sure that `e2fsck` finds the partition because if I put the wrong value in offset (e.g., 0) I get an error that the filesystem could not be found. Also, if I use `e2fsck -p /dev/sdb2?offset=67108864` after any of the approaches 1 or 2, it prints `root: clean, ...`.

I wonder if someone could point me to the documentation for the `offset` option of `e2fsck` or help me understand what it does exactly and how this differs from mounting the loopback device with a given offset.

Thanks.

EDIT: Additional information.
I can reproduce this behaviour as follows:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/disk bs=1M count=100
mkfs -t ext4 -E offset=70000000 /tmp/disk
sudo mount -o loop,offset=70000000 /tmp/disk /mnt/
ps > /mnt/test
cp /tmp/disk /tmp/disk2
cp /tmp/disk2 /tmp/disk2.copy
sudo umount /mnt 
e2fsck -p /tmp/disk2?offset=70000000
# /tmp/disk2: recovering journal
# e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to re-open /tmp/disk2
# /tmp/disk2: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********
sudo mount -o loop,offset=70000000 /tmp/disk2.copy /mnt/
dmesg | tail
# [240760.866274] EXT4-fs (loop3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
# [240770.516865] EXT4-fs (loop3): recovery complete
# [240770.516869] EXT4-fs (loop3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
sudo umount /mnt
e2fsck -n /tmp/disk2?offset=70000000
# e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
# Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
# /tmp/disk2: clean, 11/25688 files, 8896/102400 blocks
e2fsck -n /tmp/disk2.copy?offset=70000000
# e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
# /tmp/disk2.copy: clean, 11/25688 files, 8896/102400 blocks
```

As we can see mounting the file recovers the journal (and the file system is then reported as clean by e2fsck), while `e2fsck -p` throws an error and does not recover the journal.

If this can be useful, here is the difference between the two disk images[image].