# QNAP TS-251+ does not recognize data disk configuraiton after hard resetting without the disk in

Tags: partition, data-recovery, raid, nas

I have a QNAP TS-251+ NAS server with two bays. This is for home use and cloud function with mobile applications, with full disk LUKS encryption system and 2 shared and encrypted folders, I know the passwords.

In bay number 1 I had a 18TB disk  for data and in bay number 2 I had a 2TB disk used for NAS applications. Further investigation revealed a Raid 1. I did not have them configured in Raid, but searched the web there are many comments that say
Qnap disks configured in single use are Raid 1 type.

Due to network connection problems I could not access the server by any way.
I did a 3 minute reset to restore the network settings to default values, at which point the disks were in place. This did not solve the connection problem.

I tried another 10 minute reset to to factory defaults, at which point the disks were in. After the 10 minute reset, I was able to access the NAS.

I decided to do a hard reset with the 18TB disk out of the NAS. When all the configuration was reset, I connected it back to the NAS, but it did not recognize the disk 18TB configuration, only recognized the disk as new. I don't understand why.

I connected the disk to a docking station and connected it to a computer with a Linux Mint system, which was able to see all the partitions of the disk. That makes me think that everything is intact.

My question is: Is it possible to recover all the information from this disk? The disk hasn't been formatted, and is not currently in use to prevent data loss.

I don't have much knowledge of Linux.

Comment: Seems like QNAP uses LUKS, so recovery shouldn't be too hard, [here is a guide](https://jonamiki.com/2015/05/17/mount-encrypted-qnap-disk-crypto_luks-on-an-external-computer/). Everything not stated there should be solvable through this site/google. Good luck!

Comment: Hola Peregrino 69 I know that guide.
I have to explain that the disk was internal and belonged to a Raid 1. I did not have them configured in Raid, but searched the web there are many comments that say:
Qnap disks configured in single use a Raid 1 type. How can I use Linux to mount this Raid 1, decrypt and recover this data? I follow a post called: Mounting LVM Partition on RAID1 Disk from a bricked QNAP NAS. But In the end it doesn't mount, it doesn't ask me for a password.

Comment: See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64889/how-to-mount-recover-data-on-a-disk-that-was-part-of-a-mdadm-raid-1-on-another-m)

Comment: Thank you very much Panki. Unfortunately it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was the program [Recovery Explorer Professional](https://www.r-explorer.com/). It's a paid-for application, but has an unlimited Trial version with functional limitations described in the [FAQ](https://www.r-explorer.com/faq/).

It has all kinds of recovery solutions, works very well with **LUKS**, **RAID** and **eCryptFS** systems. It recognizes several types of file systems. In the end I was able to recover my files.

Comment: Welcome to the community :-) SE sites aren't discussion forums; issues aren't marked "Solved". Instead answers that resolve the issue are [accepted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), and the only one who can do that is the user asking. Answer being your own you must [wait for 48 hours](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) before accepting it. As you're new, I recommend taking the short [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and checking the Asking- and Answering -sections in [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how the site works.