# Create redundant grub bootloader on Debian

Tags: grub, uefi, redundancy

I have a Debian based server, where every partition is RAIDed, except the one that has /boot/efi. This means that I will still have all my data after a disk failure, but the system may be unable to boot.

Is there a good way to create a redundant grub install / EFI partition?

I tried mdadm RAID with v0.90 headers, but its fragile thus [unsupported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1868553). I also found that grub supports syncing multiple EFI partitions on Ubuntu, but it's also not available on Debian.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RAID 1 of /boot/efi partition on Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/644108/raid-1-of-boot-efi-partition-on-debian)

Comment: Not really. RAID is unsupported for grub because " You will get corruption the first time your EFI writes data to one of the VFAT filesystems (which EFI is allowed to do)." - See this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1868553
grub-install will even break because of this, just as in the bug report. I also tried the mentioned multi-EFI support, but it's not available on Debian.

Comment: How about just copying the contents of /boot/efi to your RAIDed disks, so if there's a driver failure, you could restore it from a rescue shell?

Comment: How about shrinking one of your RAID volumes and creating an extra VFAT partition outside the RAID volume?

Comment: My main goal would be to avoid unexpected downtime on reboot, in case my EFI disk is in a failed state. My best idea currently is to always check disk status before reboot. An optimal solution would provide multiple bootable EFI partitions, keeping in sync, even after a grub update.

Comment: So no, every **disk** can only have one grub. You cannot install grub on multiple partitions. The only possible solution would be to have a separate **disk** that you can make bootable and backup your grub on. Or even on a USB stick that can load your system in case your `/boot/efi` fails. But with just a single disk - no can do.

Comment: I mean I do have multiple disks. I want one EFI partition on more than one disk, and mirror them.

Comment: Try a partitionable Raid1 (mdp) using Superblock 1.0.