# USB Drive Software Disk Mirroring - Is this the right approach?

Tags: debian, backup, performance, raid, raspberry-pi

I have a 1TB NTFS USB Data Drive (no boot, etc...) that I would like to keep a mirror of as a backup in case of hardware failure.

It is always connected to my raspberry pi running the raspbian (debian) based raspmc.

After reviewing this question... [How to set up disk mirroring (RAID-1)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/54960/how-to-set-up-disk-mirroring-in-ubuntu)

This seems like a good solution to mirror the drive.

- Will this work as expected for USB drives?
- Am I looking at any performance loss by mirroring the drive?
- Anything I'm not considering that I should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what you'll be using the machine for, I can't give very specific advice, but yes, it can work.  The write performance penalty will be exactly as if you were running the disk strictly from a usb drive i.e. copying large files quickly to your pi.

Also, this isn't strictly an ideal backup solution, since any files that are corrupted, damaged, or accidentally deleted on the way in to your pi will be corrupted, damaged, or deleted on both disks i.e.

```
rm -rf /media/DATA
```

will render both drives completely empty (possibly recoverable, but painfully, slowly.)  If the data is valuable, the 'right' way to back it up would be to use periodic snapshots to a different drive all together.

The solution I use for my own personal data is a combination of both approaches: raid + monthly external snapshot.  A raid1 will ensure that hardware failure of either main drives will not bring your system down (and is a straightforward replacement) and the snapshot helps protect you from issues that aren't strictly disk errors.

Comment: Maybe a weekly scheduled `rsync` would be a better route?

Comment: Absolutely; I wasn't suggesting an lvm snapshot, sorry if it wasn't clear.  Whatever method you use to make the backup (rsync, cp -a, ftp, smb, morse code, is peachy in my book.)