# Is it ok to mkfs without partition number?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mkfs

I have a pen drive and one partition:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 931.5G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   1   7.5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1   7.5G  0 part
```

and I have formatted with command:

```
   # mkfs.fat -n A /dev/sdb
```

and it works fine.

But after then, I skimmed though the man page for mkfs:

```
   mkfs is used to build a Linux filesystem on a device,  usually  a  hard
   disk  partition.   The  device argument is either the device name (e.g.
   /dev/hda1, /dev/sdb2),  or  a  regular  file  that  shall  contain  the
   filesystem.   The  size argument is the number of blocks to be used for
   the filesystem.
```

It says `mkfs` should work with partition number. And my problem is why my operation works without error prompt?

Comment: there is no problem using the whole device instead of a single partition. this would more make sense if you want 3.5 G fat and 4G ext3/luckfs/whatever, then you would have to part and format each part.

Comment: If you put it in a device that expects a partition table to exist, it might ask you to format... it's usually better to have a partition table even if it's not strictly required.

Comment: The man page says the the device is ***usually** a hard disk partition*.  An entire hard disk is also a suitable block device.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Creating a filesystem on a whole disk rather than a partition is possible, but unusual. The documentation only explicitly mentions the partition because that's the most usual case (it does say *usually*). You can create a filesystem on anything that acts sufficiently like a fixed-size file, i.e. something where if you write data at a certain location and read back from the same location then you get back the same data. This includes whole disks, disk partitions, and other kinds of [block devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#BLOCKDEV), as well as regular files (disk images).

After doing `mkfs.fat -n A /dev/sdb`, you no longer have a partition on that disk. Beware that the kernel still thinks that the disk has a partition, because it keeps the partition table cached in memory. But you shouldn't try to use `/dev/sdb1` anymore, since it no longer exists; writing to it would corrupt the filesystem you created on `/dev/sdb` since `/dev/sdb1` is a part of `/dev/sdb` (everything except a few hundred bytes at the beginning). Run the command `partprobe` as root to tell the kernel to re-read the partition table.

While creating a filesystem on a whole disk is possible, I don't recommend it. Some operating systems may have problems with it (I think Windows would cope but some devices such as cameras might not), and you lose the possibility of creating other partitions. See also [The merits of a partitionless filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14010/the-merits-of-a-partitionless-filesystem)

Comment: A partitionless disk is also called a [superfloppy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-and-gpt-faq?view=windows-11#superfloppy).

Answer (score 11):

It is generally fine to put a filesystem on a whole device, rather
than partitioning and formatting the partitions, if you do not intend
to have more than one filesystem on your device. You will simply have
to be consistent; since your put the filesystem on `sda` rather than
`sda1`, you will have to mount `sda` as well, since `sda1` will not
exist at all.

The device in your question appears to be a FAT-formatted removable
drive: if it is going to be used with embedded devices that may have a
more or less detailed notion of how filesystems can be mounted, it may
be worth testing that they do in fact support a whole-device
filesystem without a partition table. (For example, cameras tend to
create a single partition and format that; it's entirely possible that
they would declare a partitionless memory card unusable.)