# Can't access data I wrote directly to volume

Tags: filesystems, mount, volume

I am running a VPS with a provider. It had CentOS and I just couldn't get a couple of things to run. So I wanted to set it up again with ubuntu server.

I asked the provider for a 10GB drive for a temporary backup, so that I would be able to just copy the data when the OS would be reinstalled without re-uploading.

I got the volume, and unfortunately I mounted it and **directly created a file system on the volume** without creating a partition first, with `mkfs.ext4`. This actually went well, I was able to copy the data to the volume, I unmounted and reinstalled the OS.

The surprise came now after booting up the new OS, I can't mount the volume back in. So I can't access the backup.

The provider just offered to try a couple of things if I would provide the root password.

I wonder, anyone able to suggest to do something before I give out my root paassword (I actually trust the guys, but always better safe than sorry).

Comment: I read this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346826/is-it-ok-to-mkfs-without-partition-number and this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14010/the-merits-of-a-partitionless-filesystem, and they both suggest that a partitionless system is possible and should work.
So the fact that it doesn't mount back anymore makes me suspicious, and now I am absolutely confused and don't recall any details. Did I mount the filesystem correctly the first time? Did it actually copy everything?

Comment: We finally were not able to recover anything, so the external disk has been removed and thus nothing else can be done. Just for the records.