# Is there a reason for a partition table on an USB flash drive?

Tags: partition, usb-drive

When I plugged in my new [SanDisk USB flash-drive](https://shop.westerndigital.com/products/usb-flash-drives/sandisk-ultra-luxe-usb-3-1#SDCZ74-256G-A46), then I noticed that it has a MBR present:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 232.88 GiB, 250047627264 bytes, 488374272 sectors
Disk model:  SanDisk 3.2Gen1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1          32 488374271 488374240 232.9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

What is the purpose of the partition table on a non-bootable USB flash drive? I guess at least under Linux it makes no difference other than mounting `/dev/sdX` instead of `/dev/sdX1` when the file system is made directly on the physical device instead of a partition on the device? In addition, the usable space for files is tiny bit larger when not using a partition table because the file system does not need to start from the beginning of the partition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The merits of a partitionless filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14010)

Comment: @Kusalananda It does, thanks!