# pvcreate: Can't use /dev/sda: device is partitioned

Tags: partition, fdisk, pv

I'm currently installing arch linux and when I try to create a physical volume it gives me this error.

```
Can not use /dev/sda: device is partitioned
```

What is this error and how can I get rid of it?

PS: I have formatted the disk with `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda`

Answer (score 11):

Upon my first attempt, `pvcreate -ff /dev/vdh` did not work for me, whether or not the disk contains a partition.

```
pvcreate -ff /dev/vdh
Cannot use /dev/vdh: device is partitioned
```

I had to use `wipefs` first to get rid of all metadata.

```
root@nextcloud:~ # wipefs --all --backup /dev/vdh
/dev/vdh : 8 bytes were erased at index 0x00000200 (gpt) : 45 46 49 20 50 41 52 54
/dev/vdh : 8 bytes were erased at index 0x9c3fffffe00 (gpt) : 45 46 49 20 50 41 52 54
/dev/vdh : bytes were erased at index 0x000001fe (PMBR) : 55 aa
/dev/vdh : ioctl call to reread partition table: Success
```

The creation of the volume was then able to be carried out correctly:

```
pvcreate -ff /dev/vdh
Physical volume "/dev/vdh" successfully created.
```

Probably I went too fast, I did not test without the `-ff` option.

Comment: Tested on Pop_OS 22.04 LTS (based on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS) and this worked perfectly, and no `-ff` is necessary when creating the physical volume with `pvcreate`. The `wipefs` command does the job of removing the GPT partition table just fine so that LVM will deal with the entire raw device directly.

Comment: You can also big hammer with dd and wipe the table header out. dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M count=2

wipefs didn't seem to help (not sure I was using it right though), but after the dd pvcreate didn't care

Answer (score 3):

For future references, there are two cases:

**1. When there are no partitions**

This may happen when you have a GPT (GUID Partition Table). Unfortunately this cannot even be forced with `-f` ([ref to a bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1977734))

You can check what partition table you have with `fdisk -l /dev/sda` for example.

The solution is to replace the GPT with a legacy BIOS table, for example with **gparted**:

- `Device` / `Create Partition Table...`
- Select new partition table: `msdos`

or with **parted**:

- `parted /dev/sda`
- `mktable msdos`
- `quit`

After which you should be able to create your physical volume:

- `pvcreate /dev/sda`

It is possible that pvcreate suggests to wipe out the dos signature found in the partition table. It is safe to do it.

**2. When there are already partitions on the disk**

It is a safety measure, and `-f` cannot override it either.

You can remove the partitions with the same solution above, since creating a new table will erase everything. There are other ways to do it, for example with `fdisk`, but the solution above makes sure you solve the GPT issue at the same time.

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me on Debian 11. +1

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/sda` is an entire disk. Usually (but not necessarily always) you would partition the disk, giving device names such as `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`, and you would use these for filesystems, swap space, LVM allocation, etc.

You have put a filesystem onto `/dev/sda` so it's no longer available for assignment to logical volume management (`pvcreate`). The LVM tool correctly warns you that the disk is already in use (with a filesystem).

If you really do want to destroy the filesystem and replace it with LVM you can read the documentation (`man pvcreate`) and see that,

> The  force  option [`-f`] will  create  a  PV  without  confirmation.  Repeating the force option (`-ff`) will forcibly create a PV, overriding checks that normally prevent it, e.g. if the PV is already in a VG.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have destroyed your system.

`/dev/sda` is the entire disk.  Normally, you will take your `/dev/sda` disk and partition it into numbered pieces `/dev/sda1` `/dev/sda2` `/dev/sda3` and so on.  Then you can use `pvcreate` to use one of these individual partitions.  `fdisk -l /dev/sda` will print you a list of the partitions on your disk.

Further, you do not want an `ext4` file system on a partition that you're going to use with LVM.  LVM uses its own data format on the partitions it creates, not a standard file system.

Comment: `pvcreate` works on disks too, in this case there is no reason to create partitions in the first place. No system was destroyed, he's installing it...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your goal was to create a physical volume from the whole disk without a partition table, then you would need to zero out any existing partition table first:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1
```

---

Note that not using a partition table may not be best practice. It may be misjudged as an unused, corrupt disk by a naive user or operating syste,.

More details in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14017/417034) answer.

Comment: Your `dd` command isn’t sufficient for disks with a GPT. [MaxiReglisse’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/701501/86440) takes care of both MBR and GPT.