# Shrink partitionless filesystem

Tags: filesystems, partition, luks, block-device, disk-encryption

I have data on a disk that I want to encrypt by cloning the full filesystem of that disk (source) to a virtual block device (devicemapper/cryptsetup) based on an additional disk (target) of identical capacity. I have already setup the LUKS device on the target disk.

The source disk has been initialized as [partitionless filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14010/the-merits-of-a-partitionless-filesystem). That meas I would need to shrink that filesystem by 2MiB (4096 blocks a 4096 bytes) to account for the additional LUKS2 header, and then `dd` the data from the filesystem on the source disk to the LUKS device.

I did a

```
resize2fs /dev/sda <newsize>
```

with `<newsize>` being the number of total blocks minus 4096, which seemed to work as expected.

However, since the source disk is partitionless, `dd` would still copy the full disk - including the 4096 blocks by which the filesystem has been shrunk.

My question now is:
can I safely assume that the free blocks from the `resize2fs` operation are located at the end of the physical device (source), and thus pass `count=<newsize> bs=4096` as argument to dd? Will this clone/copy the complete filesystem? Or any other pitfalls I did not consider?

Bonus question: In order to double check, is there already a tool available that computes the md5sums of a disk block-wise (instead of file-wise of a filesystem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question now is: can I safely assume that the free blocks from the resize2fs operation are located at the end of the physical device

Yes, that's the assumption you'd need to make even if it was a partition and you were going to shrink it.

> and thus pass `count=<newsize> bs=4096` as argument to `dd`?

Well, probably.

`dd` is a bit weird in that `dd count=N bs=M` does *not* mean that N*M bytes will be copied, just that it will issue N reads of M bytes each, and a corresponding write for each. The reads might return less than the requested number of bytes, in which case the total read and written would be less than what you wanted.

In practice, I've never seen Linux block devices return partial reads, so it should work. You should check the output, it should say something like "N+M records in" where the first number is the amount of full blocks read, and the second the number of partial blocks read. GNU dd should also warn about incomplete reads.

In any case, you might as well use `head -c $(( nblocks * 4096 ))`.

See: [dd vs cat -- is dd still relevant these days?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12532/170373) and [When is dd suitable for copying data? (or, when are read() and write() partial)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17295/170373)

(Anyway, double-check your numbers before doing anything based on a stranger's post on the Internet. It's your filesystem, and you don't want to mess it up due to someone else's typo. You probably knew that already, but anyway.)

> In order to double check, is there already a tool available that computes the md5sums of a disk block-wise

You should be able to just run `md5sum /dev/sdx`, or `head -c $bytes /dev/sdx | md5sum`.

MD5 should work fine for checking accidental corruption or a truncated copy, but note that in general, it's considered broken. Distinct files with the same hash can be created with some ease. For serious use, use the SHA-2 hashes instead, i.e. `sha256sum` or `sha512sum`.

Comment: wasn't aware of dd partial reads/writes so far.
+1 also for the disclaimer and sha256/512sum recommendation. nice!

Comment: @user236012, though if you're just using it to double-check that a copy you just made is identical to the original, MD5 should be fine. But don't trust it for anything you want to call secure.